# Reading the JSON written by the api -JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I need a fetch json data from realtime database. I tell this step by step with images and codes.

Here is my realtime database json:
[image]

And here is my fetch code:

```
get(child(dbref, 'users/')).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
          const key = childSnapshot.key
          const childData = childSnapshot.val()
          console.log(childData, '62. line "childData" console')
          const user = {
            id: key,
            value: childData,
          }
          console.log(user, '68. line "user" console')
        })
      } else {
        console.log('No data available')
      }
    })
  }
```

And here is console prints:

[image: console prints]

I need to open these files. for example:

```
key:user{
revenue:xxx,
ip:xxx,
location:xxx,
}
```

Comment: What was the problem again? I can see that you can get the snapshot value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong here, but it seems you are trying to access the properties inside `childData`?
It appears you are storing it as a string and therefore have to parse it back to JSON

```js
// Notice how "value" is a string and not an object
const data = {
    "id": "User43971",
    "value": '{"revenue": 0.000045,"ip": "45.33.97.100","country": "US","region": "Georgia"}' 
};
// To convert the "value" string back to an object, use JSON.parse:
const value = JSON.parse(data.value);
console.log(value.revenue)
```

In your case, something like this could do the trick:

```js
 const user = { id: key, value: JSON.parse(childData) }
```

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: Hello David.
I was exactly here. Thank you so much mate!